# How to display coordinate-system properties of raster data in FME Data Inspector?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, fme-form

FME Data Inspector shows detailed information of coordinate-system properties of vector data sets (marked in green). But for raster data sets FME displays in the status bar only basic information (marked in red).

How can I display detailed coordinate-system properties of raster data in FME Data Inspector?

[image]

I did not found a way to do this in google and FME-help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the raster and drag a box across it. That will return information about the raster itself (including the coordinate system) rather than just single pixel information.